# Scala "takeWhile" flow confusion

Tags: scala

I currently try to learn Scala and force me to handle as most as possible using functional programming style.

The following code has a flow that I didn't understand:

```
object Testing {
    def XForm(i: Int) = {
        println(i)
        if (i < 3) "%d".format(i * i) else ""
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        print(Range(0, 6).map(XForm).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty))
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
Vector(0, 1, 4)
```

Why is `XForm` called for values 4 and 5? I thought the 'loop' using takeWhile (in comparision to filter) is terminated on the first false occurence?

How can I solve this in a different (functional style) way?

Answer (score 2):

The `map` on `Range` is strict, so it is evaluated immediately. That is, if you remove the `takeWhile`, you'll see everything evaluates before you even get to where the `takeWhile` would happen:

```
scala> Range(0, 6).map(XForm)
0
1
2
3
4
5
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(0, 1, 4, "", "", "")
```

You can solve this by using a `view`, which will lazily evaluate the collection.

```
scala> Range(0, 6).view.map(XForm).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).force
0
1
2
3
res4: Seq[String] = Vector(0, 1, 4)
```

Comment: I used `force` at the end just to show the results, but you can rely on simply accessing the results to force evaluation.